# How to get pathInfo in twig?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I want get the pathInof in my template twig :
[image]

How i can reach pathInfo please in my template ?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is a render element of a link which gets printed in the template completely. What you find inside is for internal usage and is most times protected anyway.

To get this request parameter in your template build your own variable in preprocess:

```
$variables['path_info'] = \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo();
```

You might also need to add a cache context if your template depends on this information:

```
$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';
```

Then print it in Twig:

```
{{ path_info }}
```

This is the general approach. In this specific case if you are interested in the current path (including the base path) then you could simply use a Twig function:

```
{{ path('<current>') }}
```